# Invariant failed: You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, testcase

I am writing a test case in react for my component.
if user is not logged in and hit the URL I am redirecting to login page.

For ex.

```
describe( 'Test the component', () => {
    test("Form should have Field1, Field2, Field3 fields", () => {
        const { container } = renderWithProviders( <MyComponent />);
        const field1Field = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Field1 placeholder text');
        const field2Field = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Field2 placeholder text');
        const field3Field = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Field3 placeholder text');

        expect(field1Field).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(field2Field).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(field3Field).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

And my component file contains

```
if( !loggedinUser ) {
    return <Redirect to={{
                pathname:"/Login",
                state: {message: 'You are not authorized to view this page.'}
            }} />;
}
```

when I run my test case I get the below error

```
Invariant failed: You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>

      48 |
      49 |   // Return an object with the store and all of RTL's query functions
    > 50 |   return { store, ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) };
         |                            ^
      51 | }

      at invariant (node_modules/tiny-invariant/dist/tiny-invariant.cjs.js:14:11)
      at node_modules/react-router/modules/Redirect.js:17:9
      at updateContextConsumer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21207:19)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21652:14)
      at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27426:14)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26560:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26466:5)
      at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26434:7)
      at recoverFromConcurrentError (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25850:20)
      at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25750:22)
      at flushActQueue (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2667:24)
```

Comment: The error message is clear.